# Capturing screen with SDL?

Tags: c++, c, screen, sdl

how would i go about capturing my computer's screen with SDL?  is this possible with SDL?  i wanted to try something like applying a surface to the main renderer (if that makes any sense either) and then call:

```
SDL_SaveBMP(back_buffer, "screen.png");
```

how would i do what i want to do if it is possible?  has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done.  What you are describing is a platform dependent operation which is not implemented by SDL.

Comment: well that sucks.  are there any other methods you would prefer that i could use?

Comment: @evolon696:  You'll have to find the OS's specific API calls for each system you want to support.  Which platforms are you targeting?

Comment: debian and windows.  i am familiar with both.  suggestions?

Comment: @evolon696: For Windows-[Fastest Method of Screen Capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps: Try to create a new surface by combining all the surfaces you want to render into one( by using getpixel() and putpixel() functions -you man need to make them yourself- ), then SDL_SaveBMP( newsurface,"name.bmp") ( I personally don't know if SaveBMP can save .png files )