# Fast capturing of OpenGL framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, capture, framebuffer

I'm wondering how FRAPS captures the OpenGL framebuffer, because it seems to perform a lot better than repeated calls to `glReadPixels` (even when nothing is saved).

I have a simple OpenGL demo that looks like this:

http://puu.sh/Gat5

I know how meaningless framerates are compared to actual frame time in milliseconds, but I'm going to use it for a simple comparison here.

When running normally, I get an average frame rate of well over 8000.

When recording with FRAPS locked to 60 fps at full-size, the framerate lowers to 240.

When calling `glReadPixels` and doing nothing otherwise, the framerate is 225.

How does FRAPS manage to record *and* save the output in a reasonable amount of time? Does it use a recording thread using a very light encoding format?

Comment: Perhaps FRAPS only calls `glReadPixels` every fourth frame?  Why do you want to render extra frames that will never reach your display anyway?

Comment: The point here is not that I want to record 240 frames, but the huge decrease in rendering speed.

Comment: And my point is that FRAPS, capturing 60 frames per second, will cause less slowdown than your code, capturing 225 frames per second.

Comment: I just confirmed that by experiment, you are completely right. Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest method of screen capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben Voigt has stated, the slowdown is much less apparent when only capturing (i.e. calling glReadPixels) 30 or 60 frames per second.