# Faster way of screen capture (java)

Tags: java, screen, screenshot, capture

I find the `robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle)` method of screen capturing extremely slow.

I aim to create a smooth GIF Animation and to fulfill this I need to capture my screen (at around 1 frame per 10-30ms). Doing so whilst saving the buffered image as JPEG file slows down my applet terribly.

I got fed up and eventually stored all of the buffered images into an ArrayList before saving them (this time) all at once; and it wasn't a surprise - my applet froze for 2 minutes before crashing...

I don't mind if external programs / libraries do the task better, if you suggest the former I'd rather the program to be able to be executed in java on runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a screen capture program like fraps, which is designed for recording video?

Comment: It depends if fraps can be executed by command at runtime within java (which I don't think is possible).

Comment: I see. There appears to be a few threads about this in C++ land, so if you can't find anything, then you can always use JNI to C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JNA to access your OS's internal capture methods (like BitBlt for windows).

Comment: Problem is, my applet will be used by people with different operating systems. I don't know if JNA could "detect" a user's OS then access their internal capture methods.

Comment: You can detect OS and use JNA appropriately: System.getProperty("os.name").  If you want to support multiple OS's it won't be easy, but possible.  Dunno why the JDK is *so* slow in this regard...