# Screen pixels information in linux

Tags: linux, gpu, screenshot

Assuming root in a Linux environment, how can i obtain information about each of the pixels of the screen?

If the assumption of root is thrown out, and only basic read/write permissions are granted, what information can a simply program obtain about what is going on on the screen?

See third comment for further explanation.
thanks.

Comment: Well, you can read memory ranges from your graphic card . But why? Are X server extensions and programs like [xwd](https://github.com/johnlane/xorg-xwd/blob/master/xwd.c) not enough? Each graphic card and driver will use different memory layout for storing state, you would to look in kernel drivers for the exact memory ranges for your device..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method for screen capturing on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13479975/608639), [Screen capture program in C or C++ and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16933148/608639), etc.

Comment: My question isn't about taking screenshots, It's about understanding what memory regions (particularly ram memory) are changed by screen changes. And if those changes are induced by the changes in the screen or causing them.