# Stream video and commands on same connection or split connections?

Tags: c++, tcp, remote-access, libx264

**Background**

I am in the middle of writing a client/server app that i will install on every machine within my office (roughly 30 - 35 machines). I currently have the client connecting to the server and it has an ability to send mouse movement, mouse clicks, key strokes and execute certain commands. The next step is to stream back a video output of the screen, i am using the GDI method from [Fastest method of screen capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing) to capture the entire screen and will be using the x264 encoder to compress the frames and transmit them back to the client which will then decode and display the stream.

**Question**

is it best (by means of reducing lag, ensuring all commands are delivered as fast as possible and that streaming is as live as possible) that i transmit back along the same connection that i established for the commands, or, should i establish a separate connection on the same port, or on a different port to stream back the video?

**P.S.**

i am aware that VNC, RD and other things such as TeamViewer already exist and already do this sort of thing, but none of these support all the requirements needed for what we need within this system.

Comment: Since FTP, [RTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt), ... use split connections for data and control, I'd suggest you do the same. This way you also don't have to check each packet's type (data or control), which may increase performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split connections for a/v and commands, everyone else does this to reduce latency when sending/receiving commands to ensure all commands are processed promptly.