# Streaming windows desktop using gstreamer

Tags: windows, streaming, gstreamer, gst-launch

I have an customized i.MX6 Board which has a LCD Display connected to it. We have been streaming videos over IP using gstreamer udpsrc/udpsink pipelines..

Pipeline at PC:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=C:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86_64\\bin\\hash.h264 ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=<ip address> port=5004 sync=true
```

Pipeline on i.MX6:

```
gst-launch -v udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! vpudec low-latency=true ! imxv4l2sink sync=false
```

Is there any way I modify the PC pipeline to get the windows desktop streamed to embedded board display or what are the steps required to stream the windows desktop using gstreamer

Comment: there is no ready made plugin to capture the windows screen, but there is for xmanager (ximagesrc)

Comment: what are the other ways to achieve the requirement.

Comment: refer this link to capture https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing, once you have captured use appsrc and then do rest of the trick of streaming.

Comment: Is there any way of streaming live without capturing first and then streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The winscreencap plugin (https://github.com/agx/gst-plugins-bad/tree/master/sys/winscreencap) includes two elements for capturing windows desktops - `dx9screencapsrc` and `gdiscreencapsrc`.

Comment: Thanks.. But when I modify the plugin on PC to use dx9screencapsrc,               C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v dx9screencapsrc  ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=153.77.205.139 port=5004 sync=true.          It fails with error on the receiver side.. "No valid frames found"

Comment: Then you need to debug into that why this is the case.. SPS/PPS not received? The input source should not make a difference..

Comment: In debugging I found that "VPU is failing to decode"

Comment: maybe you want another h264parse right before the decoder. make sure x264enc operates in the right profile. It may encoder in 4:4:4 sampling which not many decoders support.

Comment: what do you mean by another h264parse

Comment: This is the error: imxvpuapi imxvpuapi_vpulib.c:1387:imx_vpu_dec_get_initial_info: could not retrieve configuration information: failure

Comment: I understood the problem may be due to different sampling, as the video mp4 play has different sampling , whereas when encoded with x264enc i get different sampling ( 4:4:4 ), how can I change it

Comment: I got it working after I change the encoder profile to Baseline: C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v dx9screencapsrc  ! queue ! videoconvert  ! x264enc  ! "video/x-h264,profile=baseline" ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=<ipaddr> port=5004 sync=true