# Applying post-effect / pixel shader to Windows

Tags: windows, colors, rendering, shader

I am color blind. This is usually not a problem for me, but whenever a game or application uses red and green as contrast colors it can become an annoyance. Looking for accessibility tools online, all I've managed to find are tools that adjust colors on snapshots, or on a camera input. For this reason, I've been toying with the idea of writing my own color adjustment tool.

Suppose I would want to write my own shader or post effect that shifts or swaps color values, then apply it to everything I see in Windows (10) in real-time - is there a way to do this? For example, is it possible to insert a pixel shader into the Windows rendering pipeline? Or would it be possible to write an application that takes the entire screen as input and outputs something else, faster than say 5ms per frame using a modern GPU? How would you approach this?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but I would try getting from and writing to the directx backbuffer. The first answer to this question shows how to get from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing-on-windows