# Does Direct3D makes calls to bitBlt from GDI32.dll

Tags: screenshot, directx-9, bitblt

I coded a demo application which uses 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-idirect3ddevice9-getfrontbufferdata
to perform screen capture of the my desktop.
My problem is when i use APImonitor I can see that when I takes screen shot, my application call *bitBlt*.
So can anyone tell me if Direct3D *getfrontbufferdata* is implemented using bitBlt?
Is there a dependence between gidi32.dll and directX ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DirectX can choose to use bitBlt, depends on your GPU caps, texture source /destination/format/size.

Perhaps you should read this :

[Fastest method of screen capturing on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing-on-windows)