# How to use 'D3d Shared Texture' method for screen shots?

Tags: windows, gpu, directx, textures, screenshot

I am trying to create a code that takes series of screenshot of a game, use Open-CV to edit it, and display it in a window, all in real-time. I am using windows operating system.  For taking screenshots I have tried almost all the methods answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing-on-windows) question. None of them gives FPS of more than 30, but do affect the performance of the game.

I found out that for games OBS Studio uses a different method called [D3d shared texture to capture frames from the game directly on the GPU.](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/inner-workings-of-desktop-video-capture.94773/post-374842).

I [searched](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/search?q=shared%20texture) for shared texture in OBS github code but I find the results confusing.
Searching on search engine does not give relevant results.

Can someone explain what is this shared texture method and how do I implement it in my code?